# how to add layers before transfer learning

Tags: python, keras, transfer-learning

I want to add attention layer before transfer learning, something like below, however, in the function `create_model_tl` I do not suppose to pass `x` yet, how to write a function to create a model so later on I can call the function to create model `myModel = create_model_tl(input_shape, mdl_type, weights)` and pass for compile and fit?

```
def attention(v, k, q, d_model, num_heads, mask):
    ......
    return output

def create_model_tl(input_shape, mdl_type, weights):
    print("start creating model - transfer learning ...")
    
    conv_layer = Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(1, 1), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape)
    x = conv_layer(x)
    x = attention(x, x, x, 16, 4, None)  # k, q, v, d_model, num_heads, mask
    base_model = vgg16.VGG16(include_top=False, input_shape=(x.shape[1], x.shape[2], x.shape[3], weights=weights)
    
    flat1 = Flatten()(base_model.layers[-1].output)
    class1 = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(flat1)
    dropout1 = Dropout(0.2)(class1)
    class2 = Dense(512, activation='relu')(dropout1)
    dropout2 = Dropout(0.2)(class2)
    
    output = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(dropout2) 
    #output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(dropout2)
    model = Model(inputs=base_model.inputs, outputs=output)
    
    return model
```